# Meteor JS & Mongo DB Finding the Next Document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So I am new to Meteor and MongoDB. I am currently having an issue finding both the previous and next document after I have queried the DB. With Laravel 4 a PHP framework and MySQL I was able to do so via the rows index id, which is numeric like so.

```
$previousProjectID = Project::where('id', '<', $project_id)->max('id');
$nextProjectID = Project::where('id', '>', $project_id)->min('id');
```

Where 'project_id' is the current project you are viewing. and when you click on either the next or previous arrays you would be able to view the corresponding project and its details.

Has anyone figured out how to do this using Meteor JS and MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$natural` to sort by storage order, although over time that wouldn't necessarily mirror insertion order. In general, if you can `sort` by a document field and batch what you fetch via `limit` on a method call or subscription, you can probably simulate next/previous actions fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is how I figured it out

```
Template.portfolioView.helpers({
  project: function() {
    return Projects.findOne({_id: Router.current().params._id});
  },
  nextproject: function() {
    if(this.project) {
      var x = Projects.find({ timestamp : { $gt : this.project.timestamp }}, {limit: 1, sort : { timestamp: 1}}).fetch();
      if(x.length < 1) {
        var y = Projects.find({ }, {limit: 1, sort : { timestamp: 1}}).fetch();
      }
      return x.length > 0 ? x[0]._id : y[0]._id;
    }
  },
  prevproject: function() {
    if(this.project) {
      var x = Projects.find({ timestamp : { $lt : this.project.timestamp }}, {limit: 1, sort : { timestamp: -1}}).fetch();
      if(x.length < 1) {
        var y = Projects.find({ }, {limit: 1, sort : { timestamp: -1}}).fetch();
      }
      return x.length > 0 ? x[0]._id : y[0]._id;
    }
  }
});
```

In the route i had to find the project as an data variable

```
this.route('portfolioView', {
  path: '/portfolio/view/:_id',
    waitOn: function() {
      return Meteor.subscribe('projects', this.params._id);
    },
    data: function(){
      return {project: Projects.findOne({_id: this.params._id})};
    },
    onAfterAction: function() {
      if (!Meteor.isClient) {
        return;
      }
      var project = this.data().project;
      SEO.set({
        title: 'Revolt Visual | '+ project.name,
        meta: {
          'description': project.description
        }
      });
    }
});
```